# Can I validate the length of something by middy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, middy

```
const baseHandler: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (event) => {
  return service.create(event.body);
}

const inputSchema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    body: {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        year: { type: "number" },
        questionId: { type: "string" },
        propSeq: { type: "number" },
        questionTitle: { type: "string" }, 
        propContent: { type: "string" },
        isTrue: { type: "boolean" },
        chapter: { type: "number" }
      },
      required: ["year", "questionId", "propSeq", "questionTitle", "propContent", "isTrue", "chapter"],
    },
  },
};

export const handler = middy(baseHandler)
  .use(jsonBodyParser())
  .use(validator({inputSchema}))
  .use(httpErrorHandler())
```

I'm writing AWS Lambda code on Serverless Framework.
I wanted request body validator like `express-validator`, so I found `middy`.
But it looks impossible to validate the length of something.
I want to force the length of `year` to 4.
for example, 2023(o), 23(x)

```
properties: {
  year: { type: "number", length: 4 }
}
```

As you guess, `length` property cannot be understood.
I don't want to add some codes to baseHandler function to validate the length.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middy uses JSONSchema, so you can use anything that is compatible with JSONSchema there. You could use `length`, but then you'd need to switch the type to `string` from `number`, as `length` is not supported for `number` (rightfully so in my opinion). If you want to keep it as `number`, then probably using range-based validation is your best bet: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#range